# We watched the workman

Tags: exam-questions, infinitive-vs-gerund, error

We watched the workman **to repair** the machine.

1.repairing
2.repair
3.no change

To me, 1st is correct. What's your opinion ?

Answer (score 3):

> We watched the workman to repair the machine.

*Watch* is an example of a verb of perception.

> We can use either the infinitive without to or the -ing form after the object of verbs such as hear, see, notice, watch. The infinitive without to often emphasises the whole action or event which someone hears or sees. The -ing form usually emphasises an action or event which is in progress or not yet completed.

We could hence use either *repairing* or *repair*, as explained above and further in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/hear-see-etc-object-infinitive-or-ing).

Comment: What is meant by "verb of perception" ?

Comment: And thank u for the dictionary link.it helped a lot.

Comment: @Manish, a verb of perception is a verb that conveys the experience of physical senses like see, watch, look, hear, listen, feel, and taste.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Seowjooheng